# 2 dimensions list (array?) in python

Tags: python

I have to create 2 functions that involve a 2 dimension list in order to make a grid for a basic Python game :

The first function must take in parameter an int n and return a list of 2 dimensions with n columns and n lines with all values to 0.

The second one must take a 2 dimension list in parameter and print the grid but return nothing.

Here is what I came with:

```
def twoDList(x, y):
   arr = [[x for x in range(6)] for y in range(6)] # x = height and y = width
   return arr

def displayGrid(arr):
      for i in range(0, 5):
        print(arr[i][i])
```

Could you please help me to improve the code regarding the instructions and help me to understand how to display the whole grid with the code please?

Comment: Try [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/)

Comment: Your first function is not even valid python syntax, and your second function will only print the values of the diagonal, twice.

Comment: Sorry guys, I knew it was lame but as I need to improve I am obliged show my mediocrity... I've edited it but still have difficulties to understand how to display the whole grid.

Comment: @atomh33ls: numpy seems like overkill for such a simple problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 methods using no 3rd party libraries.

One simple way to create a 2D array is to keep appending an array to an array:

```
for x in range(10): #width
    for y in range(10): #height
            a.append(y) #you can also append other data is you want it to be empty, this just makes it 0-9
    arr.append(a) #add the 1-9
    a = [] #clear the inner array
```

Here, I re-created the same array (`a`) 10 times, so it's kind of inefficient, but the point is that you can use the same structure with custom data input to make your own 2D array.

Another way to get the exact same 2D array is list comprehension

```
arr = [[x for x in range(10)] for y in range(10)]
```

This is probably what you were trying to do with the code you provided, which is, as mentioned in the comments, syntactically incorrect.

---

To print, just tweak the code you have to have 2 loops: one for x and one for y:

```
for x in range(5):
    for y in range(5):
        print(arr[x][y])
```

Comment: Thank you very much Arc! 
I've edited my code but still don't know how to correctly display the grid in my 2nd function.

Answer (score 0):

I still see erros in your code:

In your first function, since `x,y` are your inputs, you want to USE them in your list comprehension. You're not using them in your code

```
def twoDList(x, y):
    arr = [[x for x in range(6)] for y in range(6)] # x = height and y = width
    return arr
```

In your example, no matter what the value of x or y is, you're getting a 6x6 grid. You want to use `x` and `y` and replace the fixed values you have over there (HINT: change your '6').
Won't do that for you,

In your print function, you might want to use two variables, once per each dimension, to use as indexes.

Also, don't use fixed values in here, get them from your input (i'm guessing this is homework, so won't put the whole code)

```
def displayGrid(arr):
    for i in range(0, 5):
        for j in range(0, 5):
            print(arr[i][j])
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your advices, they are really helpful. 

In the first function twoDList, I actually want a 6x6 grid but would like to be able to change the value of each element of the grid and I have difficulties to understand how to do all that. I thought that the x and y in my code was the same as the variables in my argument? What do you mean by list comprehension?

Regarding the print function, I would like to print the whole grid so that it looks like (for example) :

1 2 0 0 2 1
0 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
2 2 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 2
0 2 2 0 2 2

Thank you very much man! ;)

Comment: Sorry, my example for the grind is displayed only on one line with the comments system of this forum.

Comment: List comprehension, a quick search on google: http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php

Comment: Your code `[[x for x in range(6)] for y in range(6)]` is a list comprehension.

Comment: I don't get what you're asking about in neither of the questions.